# How To use Model OOP in Java

Tags: java, oop

I have a Model Active Admin, I have created String ID setter and getter.
When I use setID in Login Form, I use this :

```
ActiveAdmin AA = new ActiveAdmin();
AA.setId(txtIdAdmin.getText());
```

When I test getter from login form, it works. When I test in another form, in another Java class, in different file, I can't get my string ID in Active Admin.  I used:

```
AA.getId();
```

And the result is blank.

Comment: too little code makes impossible to help you find the issue.

Comment: You need to add an example of "in another form, in another java class, in different file" in order for anyone to make sense out of it.

Comment: But please don't post thousands of lines of code. Try to come up with smallest code that demonstrates the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think your problem is that you're setting the ID on one instance of ActiveAdmin, then trying to `get()` on another instance. BTW, this really isn't an OOP kind of question, i.e. it doesn't have anything to do with the _concept_ of OOP, you're just using an OO language.

Comment: Thank you everyone, but erick, how can i try to make id to another instance?

Answer (score 0):

Build `ActiveAdmin` as a **Singleton** class, such that you have one instance for the entire application. Otherwise you will build a new object `ActiveAdmin` everytime when you use `new ActiveAdmin()`.

Check link [Java Singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html)

Answer (score -2):

Muhamad, setters and getters for properties typically take this form, based on what I think you're saying:

```
public class ActiveAdmin
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

From another class, you would say "aA = new ActiveAdmin();"
Then aA.Id = "2";  and string aAId = aA.Id;

Comment: I've been asleep longer than I thought or this is the wrong language. Also, doesn't seem to answer the question. -1

Comment: There has never been a version of Java in which this code would compile.